# Book: There Are Two Errors in the the Title of This Book

Tags: errors

*There Are Two Errors in the the Title of This Book* is a book by Robert Martin about philosophical puzzles.

Obviously the first error in the title is the repetition of the word "the". What is the second?

Comment: The second is clearly the number of errors; there's only one error, not two. (So this is a logic question and not an English question.)

Comment: Since the book is about philosophical puzzles, it shouldn't come as a surprise that the title itself illustrates a well-known _paradox_. It is a variation on [Epimenides' paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimenides_paradox), a well known self-referential paradox.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about logic and lateral thinking, not English usage.

Comment: Actually the capitalisation of the words in the title are also wrong. @FumbleFingers how is one to know unless one asks?

Comment: @mplungjan, capitalisation is generally optional for less important words like "in", "of", and "the".

Comment: @mplungjan: That's a rather bold statement to make, given there's no universal standard for title capitalisation! (Though I concede few style guides would be likely to endorse capitalising **This** but not **the**). But I find it interesting that the book cover doesn't match OP's transcription, so despite my CV I will point that out in an answer...

Comment: If Peter Shor says it's a logic question, that's good enough for me. Voting to close.

Comment: as the (*) says, read the back cover for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've closevoted because the "real" answer to the question posed in this title is as commented by @Peter Shor - the second "error" is that *there is actually only **one** error* (repetition of "**the**"). That's to say it's a matter of lateral thinking/logic, not English usage as such.

But it's worth taking a good look at [an image of the actual front cover](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1096663.There_Are_Two_Errors_in_the_the_Title_of_This_Book) to note a "third error" - not in the title of the book itself, but in OP's transcription thereof (I can't imagine why, but glancing at Google results, it seems to me *most* references to this book make the same mistake). On the book itself, both instances of the word "**The**" are capitalised...

[image]

Different style guides will differ in detail, but for this specific title, most if not all would probably stipulate consistency with "**The**" and "**This**" (either capitalise *both* - or more rarely, *neither*).